# Is it okay to train an SVM model with only one feature?

Tags: svm

I'm new to machine learning. I was doing feature selection on a bunch of features and some algorithm gave me a ranking of all features. Then I tried using just the top one feature to train the model, and the cross-validation performance turned out to be pretty good. But I'm concerned if it's appropriate to use just one feature to train an SVM model. (I'm using a RBF kernel.)
Thanks.

Comment: Is performance even better when you use more features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is ok. 
Basically, the less features you are using, the better.
Number of features have to be much less than number of training vectors. At least 100 times less.

But if in your case you have very big C value and very small G value (i.e. probably you have a very overfit model), may be you have to add more features.

Don't forget about Jaakkola’s heuristic for G estimation:
http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/tutorials/algorithms/svmModelSelection.html#jaakkola-s-heuristic

And surely use cross-validation and hold-out validation to avoid overfit.

I recommend the following book:
Max Kuhn • Kjell Johnson, Applied Predictive Modeling.
ISBN 978-1-4614-6848-6 ISBN 978-1-4614-6849-3 (eBook)
DOI 10.1007/978-1-4614-6849-3
Springer New York Heidelberg Dordrecht London

Best regards,
Nick.